# compiling SQLJ with Ant

Tags: ant, compilation, sqlj

How to compile SQLJ with ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a native sqlj Ant task.  You can start an sqlj process with the Ant [`exec` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) as if you were executing it from a command prompt.

Edit:
Link to download sqlj: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/index.html

Comment: i compiled it only from JDeveloper, how do you compile it from command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a proper task for compiling SQLj sources with Ant, however there is an old ant-user post where someone has [submitted the source](http://www.mail-archive.com/ant-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg03389.html) for an ant task.
I don't know how well it works, but it should at least point towards how it can be done.

From the Javadoc:

```
* Task to compile SQLj source files. This task can take the following
* arguments:
* <ul>
* <li>srcdir
* <li>destdir
* <li>compile
* <li>ser2class
* <li>user
* <li>url
* </ul>
* Of these arguments, the <b>srcdir</b> and <b>destdir</b> are required.
* <p>
* When this task executes, it will recursively scan the srcdir and dest
* destdir looking for sqlj files to compile. This task make its compile
* decision based on timestamp. Notice that the generated java files will
* be located at the same directory as the sqlj files, Only the binary files
* will be placed at the destdir directory.
```